# html5 webcam: remove the background and replace with an image

Tags: javascript, html, background, webcam, webcam-capture

this is my first question on Stack Overflow.
What I want is take a snapshot from a background with html5 Webcam and javascript.
Than take a second Photo with a Portrait/Person and the same background.
than cut out the background and replace it with a stored picture (e.g. an ocean), and than save that picture on the harddrive.
Any hint is appreciated.

edit: here this is made with processing, I want this made with html5 javascript and maybe additional js-libraries: http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/chapter-16/example-16-12/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow first of all! Secondly, this site is mainly designed to help you overcome programming problems when you hit a rough spot and can't get past it. To get high quality answers, be sure to post what you've tried, what result you're currently getting, and what the desired result is. Please show what you've already tried to get the highest quality answer.

Comment: got that..I did not start programming yet, I guess I asked to early, (have to learn first the "stackoverflowing") and do some more research. (I editet the question with a link)

Comment: Is http://superuser.com/ the better site to ask before programming?